# R: reading old 13F txt files from SEC Edgar database using R edgar package

Tags: r, web-scraping, txt, edgar

Hi I'm trying to read the 13F filings in the SEC edgar database using the R edgar package

The challenge I have is the filings I'm looking at is the old filing (~year 2000)
https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=1087699

They are in crappy txt format, different to today's 13F and unreadable using readtxt functions.

example file is here: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1087699/000108769999000001/0001087699-99-000001.txt

```
library(edgar)

F13<-
  getFilings(
  cik.no = "0001087699",
  form.type = "13F-HR",
  1999,
  quarter=c(1,2,3),
  useragent="myname@gmail.com"
)
```

I tried this and R is just telling me it is busy and downloading forever, it is not a very big txt file. So something is wrong. Then when it finally finished it says no filing information found for given CIKs and form type, but I'm clearly looking at the file. If the edgar package is not designed to deal with it, then how can I do it?

My end goad is to have the filings in nice dataframe, columns for stock symbols and prices and rows for stock data. little help please.

Is there any **scraping** available? I highlighted the lights by inspect in chrome, but they look weird to me (sorry, not good at **scraping** at all).

Comment: Probably that package points at the _complete submission file_ on EDGAR. If that's the case, then those are the complete backend files that fuel the rendered HTML pages you usually navigate via a browser. You could try to use some scraping packages like **rvest** even though that's not really recommended. Or, you can just develop your own scaper and pre-processing function to strip all the unwanted text. This is what I have done so far.

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti yeah man, unfortunately, I'm not that good with scrapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I parsed the file you provided as an example [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1087699/000108769999000001/0001087699-99-000001.txt). I first copied the data from the file to a txt file. The file `copied.txt` needs to be in the current working directory. This could give you an idea how to proceed.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_file("copied.txt") %>%
  # trying to extract data only from the table
  (function(x){
    tbl_beg <- str_locate(x, "Managers Sole")[2] + 1
    tbl_end <- str_locate(x, "\r\n</TABLE>")[1]
    str_sub(x, tbl_beg, tbl_end)
    }) %>%
  # removing some unwanted characters from the beginning and the end of the extracted string
  str_sub(start = 4, end = -3) %>%
  # splitting for individual lines
  str_split('\"\r\n\"') %>% unlist() %>%
  # removing broken line break
  str_remove("\r\n") %>%
  # replacing the original text where there are spaces with one, where there is underscore
  # the reason for that is that I need to split the rows into columns using space
  str_replace_all("Sole   Managers Sole", " Managers_Sole") %>%
  # removing extra spaces
  str_squish() %>%
  # reversing the order of the line (I need to split from the right because the company name contains additional spaces)
  # if the company name is the last one, it is okey that there are additional spaces
  stringi::stri_reverse() %>%
  str_split(pattern = " ", n = 6, simplify = T) %>%
  # making the order to the original one
  apply(MARGIN = 2, FUN = stringi::stri_reverse) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(c(6:1)) %>%
  set_names(nm = c("name_of_issuer", "title_of_cl", "cusip_number", "fair_market_value", "shares",  "shares_of_princip_mngrs"))

# A tibble: 47 x 6
   name_of_issuer   title_of_cl cusip_number fair_market_value shares  shares_of_princip_mngrs
   <chr>            <chr>       <chr>        <chr>             <chr>   <chr>                  
 1 America Online   COM         02364J104    2,940,000         20,000  Managers_Sole          
 2 Anheuser Busch   COM         35229103     3,045,000         40,000  Managers_Sole          
 3 At Home          COM         45919107     787,500           5,000   Managers_Sole          
 4 AT&T             COM         1957109      5,985,937         75,000  Managers_Sole          
 5 Bank Toyko       COM         65379109     700,000           50,000  Managers_Sole          
 6 Bay View Capital COM         07262L101    14,958,437        792,500 Managers_Sole          
 7 Broadcast.com    COM         111310108    2,954,687         25,000  Managers_Sole          
 8 Chase Manhattan  COM         16161A108    10,578,750        130,000 Managers_Sole          
 9 Chase Manhattan  4/85C       16161A9DQ    59,375            500     Managers_Sole          
10 Cisco Systems    COM         17275R102    4,930,312         45,000  Managers_Sole
```

Comment: hi man, thank you for helping. Strangely the code didnot work when I save the same file from SEC to txt and read it. The error code is "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Locations 6, 5, 4, 3, and 2 don't exist.
ℹ There are only 1 column."

Comment: But I tried your code line by line, and found why it didnot work. tbl_end <- str_locate(x, "\r\n</TABLE>")[1], here the \r, I dont know what is \r, it does exist in string r cheat sheet, but I see what you are trying to do, so I took r away, the \\n works. next, str_sub(start = 4, end = -3) needs to be str_sub(start = 3, end = -3) to read the America online, instead of merica online.

Comment: could you explain a bit more on the \r?  other than that, you idea and code works after tinkering. And I really like your approach, the results look clean and neat. And I can adapt this to other files that have switched the format (yes, SEC is not consistent at all). please take my humble tokens as a thank you.

Comment: @ML33M sorry to hear that the code did not work as intended. On the OS level, text files contain data and each row ends with a new line statement \n. The \n stands for new line. Some operation systems such as Windows add also \r, which is for return (i.e. OS needs to return to the beginning of the line). Since I am on Windows, for me the file contains these additional \r. I assume your OS is different, therefore you only have \n. Honestly, I did not realise that so I posted the code that worked for me.

Comment: no worries my friend, you are correct, my OS is mac. And now I learned something new, that's good for me. And frankly SEC has been a real pain, non-of their filings are consistent. The one I fixed just now failed at next quarter report...now it begins again to find where it breaks haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use `httr` package to request the page:

```
> install.packages("httr")
# follow instructions etc
```

Then in `R` shell (you might need a restart):

```r
> httr::GET("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1087699/000108769999000001/0001087699-99-000001.txt")
```

This will download the file successfully however I'm not fluent enough in R to parse this text, but it looks pretty easy: split text by `<TABLE>`, spline newlines for rows, split every row by spaces for columns.

Comment: hi, sorry I know you are on the right track but like I said I dont know how to scrap really. Besides, when I copy paste the file onto a txt file editer, I realised the spacing between columns are probably messed up: that is the 2nd row is actually the tail of 1st row, is just that for some reason the column took a turn